# Save result in more txt files

Tags: php, fwrite

```
    if (is_writable($filename2)) {
        if (!$handle = fopen($filename2, 'a')) {
            echo "Cannot open file ($filename2)";
            exit;
        }
        if (fwrite($handle, $datass) === FALSE) {
            echo "Cannot write to file ($filename2)";
            exit;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        echo "The file $filename2 is not writable";
    }
}
$filename2 = 'test.txt';
```

and this code work and the info come on `test.txt` but I want to process more files like `test.txt` and `test2.txt`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to write the same thing to multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but maybe you want to extract a function and then use that function to write to multiple files?

```
function writeToFile($filename, $content)
{
    if (!is_writable($filename2)) {
        echo sprintf(
            'The file "%s" is not writable',
            $filename
        );

        return;
    }

    $handle = fopen($filename, 'a');

    if (false === $handle) {
        echo sprintf(
            'The file "%s" cannot be opened',
            $filename
        );

        return;
    }

    $written = fwrite($handle, $data);

    fclose($handle);

    if (false === $written) {
        echo sprintf(
            'Could not write to file "%s"',
            $filename
        );
    }
}

$data = '...';

writeToFile('test.txt', $data);
writeToFile('test2.txt', $data);
```

**Note** Opening files with `fopen()` and mode `a` and then writing using `fwrite()` will append to existing files, otherwise create new files. Also, you should still close the file handle with `fclose()`, even if you were unable to write to the file.

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php